# How do I open a program in the background and exit the script with no output text?

Tags: python

For example, if I run `Popen(["firefox", "https://example.org/"])`, I get a message along the lines of

```
Gtk-Message: 21:33:04.621: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
```

Is there a way to run that same Popen (or any equivalent) and have no messages printed to the screen, and then kill the program (main.py)?

Eg:

```
command(["firefox", "https://example.org/"])
exit(0)
```

> Opens firefox, then automatically exits the program, leaving the `command()` still active, and with no output from `command()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just have to start a new detached session and null stderr and stdout

```py
from subprocess import Popen
import subprocess
import os

process = Popen(["firefox", "https://example.org/"],
                stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                start_new_session=True)
exit(0)
```

Comment: without context manager, just use `subprocess.DEVNULL`